# Sabre international flight offers from MIA to UVF 404 not found

Tags: http-status-code-401, sabre

I am trying to query cheapest flights from Miami to Saint Lucia and I got 401

```
https://api-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com/v1/shop/flights/fares?origin=MIA&destination=UVF&lengthofstay=10&departuredate=2021-01-15
```

If I do the same from New York to London, I got 200 OK

```
https://api-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com/v1/shop/flights/fares?origin=JFK&destination=LHR&lengthofstay=10&departuredate=2021-01-15
```

There are daily flights from Miami to Saint Lucia

Answer (score 0):

Not every city pair for flights is supported in CERT so you may need to find a new city pair to use for testing. I do not know of a way to determine which pairs are supported and which are not, your Sabre contact may know more about that.

Answer (score 0):

I got the data by sending a POST request to `https://api-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com/v2/offers/shop`